# Android does not boot because of missing apk files in system/app folder

Tags: adb, boot, root-access, superuser, system-apps

I moved the question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/15872848/1665807

I have a rooted Huawei u8825d phone.I want to know if there were no apk files in "/system/app/" folder.

So,I moved these apk files from /system/app/ to internal sd-card.When I tried to reboot the phone,it didn't succeed.I hanged up with a white screen.

Then I tried to push the apk files from the internal sd-card into the /system/app/ folder by using "adb".

```
D:\MTH\update>adb devices

List of devices attached

78F5FD6420D5 device

D:\MTH\update>adb remount

remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Then,in another way,

```
D:\MTH\update>adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

mount: Operation not permitted
```

This is another way.

```
D:\MTH\update>adb shell

shell@android:/ $ su

su

Segmentation fault

139|shell@android:/ $
```

Comment: Bad luck. Without the SuperUser/SuperSU app installed, you can hardly `su` -- and since you removed all system apps from `/system/apps`, there is none left. This means you're in a "doom loop": in order to get your files back to `/system`, you need to remount `/system`. To do that, you need to `su`, for which you need the files in `/system/apps`... I'd say you probably will end up flashing your ROM again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root access or SuperUser is an apk that resides in `/system/app`. If you remove it with the rest of the apps, you lose root. As a possible workaround, you can try to run:

```
> adb root
> adb shell
```

And see if the shell that adb opens is `$` (normal user) or `#` (root). If you're logged as a normal user, I'm afraid you will need to reinstall root in your phone.

Also, `/system/app` is like `C:\Windows` or `/bin` (in Linux), if you remove the files there, don't expect the device to run, as it won't have the necessary files to do so.

Comment: As I wrote above: with no SuperUser/SuperSU running, John will most likely end up having to re-flash. Though the `su` itself in in a different location (`/system/bin` or `/system/xbin`), it usually also needs SuperUser/SuperSU to get a root prompt. And the latter he just successfully removed. One thing he *could* try is creating a suitable `update.zip` to be flashed from recovery.